# Android - getFilesDir().lstFiles() returning null?

Tags: java, android, file-handling

I want to read out the first line of each file in my app's private filesdir.
I am using following code:

```
    String[] f ={};
    File[] files = con.getFilesDir().listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i<=files.length-1; i++){
        try {
            FileInputStream in = con.openFileInput(files[i].getName());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            f[i]=br.readLine();
            br.close();
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("File input reading", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return f;
```

Logcat always says "E/File input reading﹕ length=0; index=0" - means that the length of the files array is 0, because listfiles() returned null, but there is definitely a file in this directory. why is it not being recognized by listfiles()?

---

EDIT:
I solved it with this code:

```
public static String[] GetFiles(Context con){
    File[] files = con.getFilesDir().listFiles();
    String[] f = new String[files.length];
    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        f[i] = getFirstLine(files[i], con);
    }
    return f;
}

public static String getFirstLine(File f, Context con){
    String ret ="error";
    try {
        FileInputStream in = con.openFileInput(f.getName());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        ret = br.readLine();
        br.close();
        in.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("File input reading", e.getMessage());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It reads the first line out of each file in the app's private filesdir.

Answer (score 0):

> because listfiles() returned null

No, it did not. Otherwise, you would have a `NullPointerException` when executing `files.length`.

> Logcat always says "E/File input reading﹕ length=0; index=0"

It would help if your `Log` call were:

```
Log.e("SomeIdentifyingTag", "File input reading", e);
```

Then, you would see the Java stack trace and the full details of the exception.

One bug is here:

```
f[i]=br.readLine();
```

`f` is a zero-length array. You cannot assign anything any of its elements, because it has no elements. If you want `f` to have the same number of elements as does `files`, you need to initialize `f` as `new String[files.length]`, sometime after you have initialized `files`.

Another bug is that you are not checking to see if `files[i]` is a file or a directory. IIRC, `listFiles()` can return directories, including virtual directories like `.` and `..`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i used your hint for the array initializaton. you can see my edit above for my solution. (btw, i dont need to check if its a fle or directory, because there only will be files)